# How does Vagrant know that machine has booted?

Tags: vagrant

I am setting up a Vagrant box with VMWare Fusion provider. I am using loading an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server 64-bit box. I am unable to boot the machine and I was wondering, how does Vagrant detect that the machine has booted?

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it asks about general computing, questions of which should be asked on [su].

Comment: In my opinion this is not off-topic, but it could have been easily answered if he took a look at the source code, which is what Frederic did below.

Comment: StackOverFlow is about the exchange of experiences after all, Frederic knew where to get this information from, and I would know where to get other information from. I was looking at `mitchellh` github account, but I did not think it was the formal source code for Vagrant because it is in a user name. I looked for it in `Hashicorp`'s github account.

Comment: Also in http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: `software tools commonly used by programmers;`. Vagrant is a software tool. Not off-topic.

Comment: @zed The tool isn't a programming tool and nor is a tool used specifically by programmers, therefore your question is off-topic.

Comment: Do you realise that there are 6 thousand questions on SO tagged `vagrant` @cybermonkey?

Comment: @zed Of course, but it depends on the topic of a question whether it is off-topic or not. Your question asks about software configuration for a program that is not a tool specifically used by programmers; that's off-topic.

Comment: There are 162 pages of unanswered [tag:vagrant] questions, given ~15 questions per page that makes 2,430 questions unanswered, or a whopping 40% of questions in that tag. Note that I'm *not* saying the tag is off-topic, rather questions which have no programming context (like yours).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vagrant just loop with ssh command to the VM and see what is the answer of this command.

you can check the [source code](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb#L45) for the detailed implementation

you can see when running `vagrant up` the default output; It retries a few times till it can issue the ssh command

```
==> app1: Booting VM...
==> app1: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    app1: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    app1: SSH username: vagrant
    app1: SSH auth method: private key
    app1: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    app1: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    app1: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> app1: Machine booted and ready!
```